# Total Supply manipulation after moving to a new standard with _mint function

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, local-variables

How can I access `totalSupply` after refactoring to using a `_mint` function instead of local state?
I will need this to make transfers from the owner to another address.
Does this example show that this supply will be fixed and immutable?
What about mutability?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now `totalSupply` is a function if you need its value.

You can modify it by using `_mint` and `_burn`.

If the tokens were already assigned to the owner it can transfer them directly.